# A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove) at C++

Tags: c++

sages of stackoverflow. There is a problem that occures constantly with heap removal in my destructor.The problem is described with *A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove)* error. But I can't figure out where I am wrong: I allocated some memory in my constructor and,then , freed that memory with my operator`delete[]` in my destructor. No more any kinds of memory removal happen. So what's the problem.
Code:

```
String():str(NULL), length(0)
{
    str=new char [100];
    cout<<"Default constructor has been used"<<endl;}
String( const char* ko)
{

str=new char [strlen(ko)];
strcpy(str,ko);
cout<<endl;
length=strlen(ko);
cout<<"The object is initialized"<<endl;
}

String(String &y)
{
    length=y.length;
    str=new char[length];
    strcpy(str,y.str);
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Destructor:

```
~String ()
{
length=0;
char* spp=str+1;
delete[] str;/*Here is the point of error(btw if get this  operator out the code the programm works fine)*/
str=NULL;
cout<<spp;
}
```

Comment: When allocating strlen() bytes and using strcpy() - you are writing 1 more byte into allocated memory then you have allocated. You've got a corrupted heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strlen` does not include the `null` terminator, therefore you must add `1` to the amount that you allocate:

`str = new char [strlen(ko) + 1];`

Without doing this, `strcpy()` will write off the end of the allocated memory and corrupt whatever is there.

Comment: You are also calling `cout << spp` after `delete`ing the memory it points to, which is a separate problem.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't expect the problem might be so obvious:)